# Selenium Timeout - Expected Condition returning False

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, gui-testing

I'm coding a bot in Python that plays tic-tac-toe. The game is a Web app written in React.js and is equipped with an AI of its own that utilizes minimax. The user (which the Python bot simulates) is always X, the AI is always O, and the user always moves first. The Python bot plays by randomly selecting unmarked squares (this is only to demonstrate automated UI testing).

**I was getting stuck inside a recursive function.**

*for loop and recursive call:*

```
        for i in clickedSquares:
            if not winner:
                self.checkForWinner(load_browser, winner)          
            elif i == random_square:
                self.test_playTTT(load_browser)
            else:
                clickedSquares.append(random_square)
```

To fix this issue I added the **if not winner** condition where "winner" is a string. This does terminate the loop; however, I'm getting an error as soon as the checkForWinner() function is called because winnerOh is always false.

```
        winnerOh = WebDriverWait(load_browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Tags.resultOh)))
        winnerEx = WebDriverWait(load_browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Tags.resultEx)))
        tiedGame = WebDriverWait(load_browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Tags.resultTie)))
```

I'm looking for an element on the UI that declares the winner: X or O or tie, which will only appear if the game is over.  So WebDriverWait().until() is timing out waiting for that element to appear, but it hasn't yet, because it's only the second move in the game.

I'm not sure how to fix this issue. If I remove the call to checkForWinner() the bot will get stuck in the recursive call to test_playTTT(). The browser will not close after the game is over, and the test will not end successfully.

**Is there another way to check the UI for the element I'm looking for that won't immediately return a False condition?  Is there a better way for me to write this for loop?**

Included below is the full Python method.

```
class TestCase_PlayRandom():
    
    URL = "http://localhost:3000"
    
    @pytest.fixture
    def load_browser(self, browser):
        browser.get(self.URL)
        yield browser

    def test_playTTT(self, load_browser):

        squares = [Tags.square1,Tags.square2,Tags.square3,
                   Tags.square4,Tags.square5,Tags.square6,
                   Tags.square7,Tags.square8,Tags.square9]
            
        clickedSquares = []
        random_square = randint(0,8)
        time.sleep(5)
        winner = ''

        if not clickedSquares:
            element = load_browser.find_element(By.XPATH, squares[random_square])
            element.click()
            clickedSquares.append(random_square)

        for i in range(0,9):
            if squares[i] == Tags.ohSquare:
                clickedSquares.append(i)
            
        for i in clickedSquares:
            if not winner:
                self.checkForWinner(load_browser, winner)          
            elif i == random_square:
                self.test_playTTT(load_browser)
            else:
                clickedSquares.append(random_square)
            
        element = load_browser.find_element(By.XPATH, squares[random_square])
        element.click()

    def checkForWinner(self, load_browser, winner):

        winnerOh = WebDriverWait(load_browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Tags.resultOh)))
        winnerEx = WebDriverWait(load_browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Tags.resultEx)))
        tiedGame = WebDriverWait(load_browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Tags.resultTie)))
    
        if winnerOh:
            winner = 'O'
            LOGGER.info('Winner O')
            return winner
        elif winnerEx:
            winner = 'X'
            LOGGER.info('Winner X')
            return winner
        elif tiedGame:
            winner = 'None'
            LOGGER.info('Tie')
            return winner
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    def checkForWinner(self, load_browser, winner):

        winnerOh = WebDriverWait(load_browser, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Tags.resultOh)))
        winnerEx = WebDriverWait(load_browser, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Tags.resultEx)))
        tiedGame = WebDriverWait(load_browser, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Tags.resultTie)))
    
        if not winnerOh:
            winner = 'O'
            LOGGER.info('Winner O')
            return winner
        elif not winnerEx:
            winner = 'X'
            LOGGER.info('Winner X')
            return winner
        elif not tiedGame:
            winner = 'None'
            LOGGER.info('Tie')
            return winner
```

invisibility_of_element_located() will return True if the element is not found on the UI and False if it is.

You'll need to play with where to put the call to the function.  I'd place it above the for loop instead of in it.

Comment: That's only going to work until the UI element does appear.  until() will keep calling that method until the return value isn't False. Then I'll get a failure.  This let the bot complete the game, however, so that's definitely an improvement.